# Fedora 10 setting up HPLIP for HP Deskjet F4488

Tags: linux, printing, fedora-10, hplip

I had set up a newly purchased HP F4488 using HPLIP, I installed it on my Fedora 10 desktop and it worked fine for the past 2 days. Suddenly, it is failing to print. The scanner works and the photocopier works. When a print job is initialized there is an error and the printer gets disabled.

What is the problem? Is there anything that I should fix additionally to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about that specific HP printer, but my HP LaserJet P1550 (or something like that... :-) has somekind of hardware bug in it. Regardless of the OS, if the paper runs out during a print job, concurrent printing attempts will fail even if you provide more paper for it.

To fix that I need to power cycle the printer. Not by merely pushing the power button. No, that would be way too easy. Instead I need the unplug the power cord, let it be for a while (say, 2 minutes) and re-plug the power cord. Voila, printing works again!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the settings in the CUPS web interface?

http://localhost:631

Answer (score 0):

First try looking at the system logs (always a good idea under Linux :-) ). In this case that would be

- /var/log/syslog
- /var/log/messages
- /var/log/cups/*

Usually the error message there will help you along. Also, the CUPS web interface (http://localhost:631/ as indicated in Iain's answer) will usually show the error.